# Why doesn't c# find the attribute? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 checkboxes, below each checkbox is a div. Each checkbox is responsible for showing or hiding the checkbox that is below it.
for example:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" myDiv="divRegisteration" myText=" הרשמה - " runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="18px" Font-Bold="true" Text=" הרשמה - הצג" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
    <div id="divRegisteration" runat="server" visible="false">
```

the checkbox 'CheckBox1' is responsible for showing or hiding the div "divRegisteration", which is addressed in the custom attribute "myDiv".

problem is, in the code behind, it does not find the attribute "myDiv":

```
if (((CheckBox)(sender)).Checked==true)
{
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(sender);
  object div = FindControl(chk.Attributes["myDiv"]); //// it does not find myDiv, and therefore doesn't find the control so the program crashes.
  HtmlGenericControl addressDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)(div);
  addressDiv.Visible = true;     
}
```

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 21:             object div = FindControl(chk.Attributes["myDiv"]);

Comment: Are you 100% sure that chk.Attributes["myDiv"] returns empty value?

Comment: yes, for some reason all the attributes that it finds are CssStyle and Keys. i dont even know where those came from.

Comment: Well, then it seems that you are targeting wrong check box... obviously since you have some attributes you did not put in there

Comment: impossible, since it is the only checkbox on the page that is check and if (((CheckBox)(sender)).Checked==true) returns true..

Answer (score 3):

Because the Attributes collection doesn't work that way:

> Gets the collection of arbitrary attributes (for rendering only) 
>   that **do not correspond** to properties on the control.

If you want to have properties like that, you need to create your own custom control that has the properties you want. Or, as an alternative, create a UserControl that hosts a single CheckBox and associated div or whatnot -- then you can just reference the one related div by ID in the codebehind. Instantiate multiple instances of that control, and you're good to go.

Edit: my WebForms-fu is a bit rusty, but here goes nothing.

The control class:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace UserControlExample {
    [ParseChildren(false)]
    public class TogglePanel : UserControl {
        private CheckBox cbToggleContent = new CheckBox();
        private Panel pnlContentPlaceholder = new Panel();

        public TogglePanel() {
            Load += OnLoad;
        }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
            Controls.Add(cbToggleContent);
            Controls.Add(pnlContentPlaceholder);

            if (!IsPostBack) {
                cbToggleContent.Checked = Checked;
                pnlContentPlaceholder.Visible = Checked;
            }

            cbToggleContent.AutoPostBack = true;
            cbToggleContent.CheckedChanged += (s, args) => {
                pnlContentPlaceholder.Visible = cbToggleContent.Checked;
            };
        }

        protected override void AddParsedSubObject(object obj) {
            pnlContentPlaceholder.Controls.Add((Control) obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And its usage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="UserControlExample" Assembly="UserControlExample" %>

<a:TogglePanel Checked="True" runat="server">
    This stuff here will be shown or hidden based on the checkbox
</a:TogglePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do i create a user control?

Answer (score 1):

`FindControl` only searches the current naming context and does not traverse a hierarchy.  By calling `FindControl` they way you are, it is using `this.FindControl`.  Try something like `chk.Parent.FindControl(...)` if the `div` is a sibling of the `CheckBox`

Edit:

Ah, well, the Attributes collection is "for rendering purposes only".  It doesn't appear to be populated with attributes specified in the ASPX HTML declaration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx

Comment: The problem is actually that it does not find the Attribute, and not the actual control..

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - doesn't the checkbox have an [InputAttributes collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx)?

Admittedly, an untested stab:

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(sender);
object div = FindControl(chk.InputAttributes["myDiv"]);
```

Does something like that work?